# 'x' must be an array of at least two dimension

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 20 variables and 20000 observations. I first convert this into all boolean values to indicate whether each original value is above some threshold (here, the threshold is `>=1`).

Each set of 10 variables makes up a group. I want to filter the data to remove any row that has 5 or more above-threshold values for any group. How can I do that?

I tried following, but the second line produces an error message:

```
MyData_filter <- as.matrix(MyData[1:20] >= 1)
keeps <- apply(MyData_filter, 1,function(x) {! any(rowSums(x[1:10])>=5) && any(rowSums(x[11:20])>=5) })
MyData_Filtered<- MyData_filter[keeps, ]
```

```
Error in rowSums(MyData_filter[1:10]) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your use of `rowSums`, which expects a 2-dimensional input. But you are `apply`ing a function one row at a time, and so the `x` input is a 1-dimensional vector.  Change `rowSums` to just `sum`:

```
function(x) {! any(sum(x[1:10])>=5) && any(sum(x[11:20])>=5) })
```

Also, if I understand your question correctly, the `!` should be applied to both criteria, but right now it's only affecting the first criterion.  So change `! any() && any()` to `!(any() && any())`.

---

Here's an alternative approach that doesn't use `apply`:

```
# create example data
set.seed(1234)
MyData <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(200, 0, 2), 10, 20))

# convert to true/false for above threshold
MyData_filter <- MyData >= 1

# perform your 10-columns-at-a-time check
keeps <- rowSums(MyData_filter[ , 1:10])<5 & 
         rowSums(MyData_filter[ ,11:20])<5

# filter your data according to that 10-columns-at-a-time check
MyData_Filtered <- MyData_filter[keeps, ]
```